# Email body regex search

Tags: regex

Here is an example email body:

> Name: Jah Selassie
>   Store Locator: Finland
>   Service Number: alphanumeric

I am looking for a regex to search through the body of an email and check for a location entry after "Store Locator".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To match on the end of line:

```
Store Locator:\s*([^\r\n]*)
```

Answer (score 0):

^Store Locator: ?(.*)$